# Empty Space, Text Formatting, Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, text-formatting

When I use `="""" & TEXT("1468", "# ###") & """"`, `"1 468"` is returned. Perfect.

However, once 4 digits become 3 digits, I get an empty space at the beginning. `" 468"`. Not perfect.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is6mE.png)

What text format can I use to avoid that empty space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the inner portion in `TRIM( )`:

`="""" & TRIM(TEXT("468", "# ###")) & """"`

`TRIM` removes superfluous leading, trailing and interposed space characters.

Comment: Wow. Perfect. Thank you so much! Is it possible to do something similar with the custom number format? Tried here: https://i.imgur.com/ixgwSmG.png

Comment: Try this custom number format: `[<1000]\"0\";[>999]\"# ##0\";0;@`

Comment: Dang. You are a genius. Thank you for that, Erik. It works in the sense that the values are finally properly centered (no longer having empty spaces in front that make everything look weird). Since I do not fully understand the format you have shared here, may I ask one more question? I used quotation marks to easily illustrate the empty space. I do not intend to use these otherwise. How should I adjust your format to exclude quotation marks, and what do I have to change if there are really many digits (like 10 digits instead of 4 digits)?

Comment: If you explain fully what you are trying to do, it will be a more efficient use of our time. For now, to get rid of the quotes, eliminate the four instances of `\"` from the custom format string.

Comment: That worked better. Appreciate it. https://i.imgur.com/qtakyRP.png What I am trying to fully achieve is apply the black-line format without empty spaces. That would be like the red-line format (your format), but it does not work properly for larger digits. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: What is the data that you are trying to format? Phone numbers with or without the leading country code? Something else? What is the *full realist range* of possible returns? Solutions are built around specifics, and so far I don't feel I have them all defined for me clearly.

Comment: These are basically YouTube video views, so it is not realistic that I have more than 10 digits per row (which is why I set the formatting to # ### ### ##0, but that leaves a lot of empty spaces at the beginning when there are fewer digits).

Comment: As it is doubtful that you will have more than 1B views for a YouTube video. If you can live with a max of 999,999,999 then this will work: `[>999999]### ### ##0;[>999]### ###;0;@`. That is as high as in-place formatting will take you. If you want to format numbers of 1B of larger, you'll need a second column with a formula (you can hide the raw data column or sheet) or a script.

Comment: Nice. This works like a charm. I have a pivot table that sums up numbers in the billions, but I just realized that I can keep the numbers aligned to the right instead of centered for that specific table. For the rest, 9 digits will indeed be more than enough. Thank you enormously for your help, Erik. These empty spaces had been bugging me for a long time. No longer, thanks to you!

Comment: Glad to have squashed the bug.